# gcc implicit signedness of constants

Tags: c, gcc, signedness

I've encountered some interesting behavior with gcc's interpretation of the signedness of constants. I have a piece of code which (greatly simplified) looks like the below:

```
#define SPECIFIC_VALUE 0xFFFFFFFF

//...

int32_t value = SOMETHING;
if (value == SPECIFIC_VALUE) {
    // Do something
}
```

When I compile the above, I get the `warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]`

All well and good -- it seems that gcc interprets the hex constant as unsigned, and doesn't like the comparison to a signed integer. However, if I change the define to something like `#define SPECIFIC_VALUE 0x7FFFFFFF`, the warning goes away. Again, I'm not particularly surprised -- the sign bit being a zero would make gcc happier about interpreting the constant as a signed value. What really surprises me is that if I change the definition to be `#define SPECIFIC_VALUE INT32_C(0xFFFFFFFF)`, I STILL get the warning. I would expect explicitly telling the compiler to interpret my constant as a signed value would silence the warning.

Comment: No `int32_t` can ever be equal to `0xFFFFFFFF`.  If you want `-1`, write `-1`.

Comment: `INT32_C(X)` is not in ISO C, but is supposed to apply the integer suffix for an `int32` to `X`.  It isn't a cast.  On a system with 32-bit int, there will be no suffix for 32-bit ints so this macro will have no effect on the argument.

Comment: @Matt McNabb  `INT32_C(X)` is in C11 "Macros for minimum-width integer constants" §7.20.4.1 1

Comment: @chux Oh cool. I was looking under inttypes.h but turns out it's in stdint.h

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read [C11](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) **§ [6.3.1.1](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.1.1)** about the conversions applied to integers. **§ [6.4.4.1](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.4.4.1p5)** ¶5 specifies the type given for an integer constant. gcc should stick to these rules.

The hex constant *is* actually unsigned (by the standard) `int` (presuming 32 bit integers). So that conforms and is not by chance!

If you clear the MSbit, the constant can be represented as (signed) `int`, however. So the comparison goes well. Still standard.

The third message is lacking the definition of `INT32_C`, so I cannot help with that. But I think you can solve that yourself now. Just keep in mind, that the error cannot be detected inside the `#define', but only after the macro has been expanded.

General rule is to either add `U` to the constant (yes, also for hex) if you really want `unsigned`. Or cast the constant:

```
#define UVALUE ((uint32_t)0x7FFFFFFF)
```

That would be even better here, as it does not rely on the size of `int` actually.

Comment: @iharob: Thanks. Everyone seems to do this different.

Comment: `((int32_t)0xFFFFFFFF)` overflows, since the maximum value of `int32_t` is `0x7FFFFFFF`. The value is *probably* going to be `-1`, but strictlyi speaking it's implementation-defined.

Comment: Yeah, I just tried that. Should have listened to my own advice actually. I only use hex for unsigned, that was my error: stick to your pattern. Edited (yes: both changes are intented).

Comment: Ok, that should be ok now.

Comment: Many compilers use different integer literal rules if not invoked in standard-conforming mode

Comment: @MattMcNabb: 1) I generally presume standard conformance if not mentioned otherwise. 2) Too lazy to verify, but iirc gcc does not change _that_ behaviour in gnu-mode (does it actually change any of the standard behaviour or just enable its extensions? And does any extension change standard behavior? - Hmm, I might check that some day).

Comment: @Olaf one difference that comes to mind is that some constants that would be `unsigned int` in ISO C90 are taken as `long long` in GNU89 (the default mode)

Comment: @MattMcNabb: From gcc 4.8.4 manual: "The default, if no C language dialect options are given, is -std=gnu90" (pew, lucky me;-). For gcc 5.1 it is even C11 (which surprises me a bit, I had assumed C99 as being the most commonly used, I think).